# Removing an element by value rather than position from a square vector

Tags: c++, sudoku

as part of some implementation for a sudoku gameboard, each square is given a set of possible values, and a row and column number.

I did this through a square vector with a set for the possible values, where certain values would be removed from the set of possible values, adhering to the rules of sudoku (eg in the same x and y values, or in the same subsquare)

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to remove a specific value from the set, I had it set up like this:

```
 vector< vector< std::set <int> > > gameboard;
```

.. double for loop here to cycle through the grid ...

```
 int removeValue = *gameboard[x][y].begin();


 gameboard[x][y].erase(removeValue);
```

But I'm pretty sure thats just removing the value at whatever position in the vector, which isn't what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Yup. You no longer have a square. Recommend using an impossible value as a sentinel you can set and test for.

Comment: I know you never intended to iterate through the set, but since you are derefrencing an iterator, you can get UB if the set's begin() == end().

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for removing a value from the set looks good.  However, I don't think you got the right value.

```
int removeValue = *gameboard[3][3].begin();

std::set<int> &rSquare = gameboard[3][3];       // get the set
std::set<int>::iterator iter = rSquare.begin(); // get an iterator
int first_possibility = *iter;                  // retrieve first possibility in set
```

When you want to remove a specific value from a set, you already know what value you want to remove. You just need to do that, exactly as you have in the second line you gave.

```
gameboard[x][y].erase(removeValue);
```

Here's a full working demo of creating a 9x9 grid, initializing all possibilities, and then removing a specific possibility:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

std::set<int> initialize_square(){
    std::set<int> all;
    for (int value = 1; value <= 9; ++value)
        all.insert(value);
    return all;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector< std::set <int> > > gameboard;
    gameboard.resize(9);
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++x){
        gameboard[x].resize(9);
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y){
            gameboard[x][y] = initialize_square();
        }
    }

    std::set<int> &possibilities = gameboard[3][3];

    std::cout << "possibilities before removing '5' are: ";
    for (int n : possibilities)
        std::cout << n << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // remove 5 from a specific cell
    // I would use possibilities.erase but this proves your syntax was good
    int value_to_remove = 5;
    gameboard[3][3].erase(value_to_remove);

    std::cout << "possibilities after removing '5' are: ";
    for (int n : possibilities)
        std::cout << n << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```